# use gazebo with walltime

Tags: ros, gazebo, trajectory-msgs, rostime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to use gazebo with walltime, so that the movement of the robot is exactly the same like in the real world. For example I used the trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory message and set up one trajectory point with [..].time_from_start = ros::Duration(10.0), but the robot's arm moved much faster. How can this be done?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9926/use-gazebo-with-walltime/) by [yuLenDo](https://answers.ros.org/users/512/yulendo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-05-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

with updateRate less than zero Gazebo tries to match simulator::GetSimTime() + simulator::GetPauseTime() with simulator::GetRealTime().  If you are seeing "simulation speedup to catchup", that means GetPauseTime() is not returning the correct value.  Can you reproduce the behavior?

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.ros.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2011-06-17**:
The gazebo mailing list on gazebo.willowgarage.com

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2011-05-16**:
OK, I will see if I can do it reproducibly.  Incidentally where is a good place to post queries about gazebo internals?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to this [webpage](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/wiki/GazeboProblemResolutionGuide) setting the  tag in the physics section of your gazebo world file to a negative number will cause the simulation to try to run in real time.  This seems to be based on some form of timestamp mechanism - I have noticed on occasion that if my simulation is paused and then restarted the sim will run at a higher rate to catch up.

---

Originally posted by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) with karma: 586 on 2011-05-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1